# Executable HTML/Javascript Applications on the Desktop?

Tags: firefox, web-applications, webkit, xul

I'm wondering if there is a way to create a Desktop Application that is essentially a Browser, except that it only runs my Application, doesn't need installation and is a static executable that contains the HTML/Images/CSS/JavaScript packaged into it, with an option to access arbitary embedded resources through JavaScript?

I believe Mozilla/Firefox allows this through their XUL Framework, which is actually used for Applications (see [Celtx](http://celtx.com/)). However, the last time I looked into it (~3 years ago), it was a horrible experience and overly complicated.

Has this changed? Or is there a WebKit based option?

Comment: What's wrong with an offline application running in a browser?

Comment: Can you give an example of what it would do? Why can't it just be a regular page in a regular browser?

Comment: @Raynos @jodes Because people would have to have a sufficiently modern browser installed, and I don't want to rely on that. Also, javascript behaves wildly different in browsers, run into security problems ("Internet explorer has blocked this potentially unsafe code") and might give issues with caching, cookies and potentially more. That's why I want a standalone, isolated browser. Essentially XUL in good.

Comment: @MichealStum I was suggesting you publish the website in a single folder with all the servers offline and get the client to browser the website locally using JS and localStorage. As long as your using IE8+ it should work as an offline website.

Comment: @Raynos That still has two problems: If people don't have IE8 or any other browser installed it doesn't work, and if you run a website from a folder in IE you might still run into security issues (IE7 or 8 does block some content unless you click the yellow bar, even if it's local), IE8 might switch into IE7 compatibility mode. Too many headaches, too many dependencies.

Comment: @MicheaelStum look at it differently. If users are willing to install your desktop application there willing to install a different desktop application (namely chrome) ;)

Comment: @Raynos No, they are not :) Been there done that. And even if they install Chrome, the next question becomes: "Now what?" - opening the index.html in Chrome isn't obvious to non-tech people, especially since Double Clicking may open it in the IE6/7 that's their default browser. Also, maybe Chrome 23 breaks something that I didn't anticipate because it worked fine in Chrome 17 when I tested. Also, Installing Apps isn't the idea anyway - Download, Extract, Run. Installers are a relic of the 90's IMHO. Looking into XULRunner and Appcelerator at the moment. The point is to remove the dependency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I went with [XULRunner](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XULRunner) in the end. The latest version is much improved over the one I looked at several years ago.

Answer (score 1):

You should try [Chromeless](https://mozillalabs.com/chromeless/).

Answer (score 1):

> > > .. doesn't need installation and is a static executable that contains the HTML/Images/CSS/JavaScript packaged into it, with an option to access arbitary embedded resources through JavaScript?

Chrome supports [`.crx`](http://code.google.com/chrome/apps/docs/developers_guide.html#live) files which is essentially a zip file with the resources archived into it. It doesn't technically require installation since it's run on the Chrome browser itself.

I know it's not directly relevant to your question but I think building web apps with HTML5, CSS3 and JavaScript is the way to go.  [You can even package it and have it install like an app](http://code.google.com/chrome/apps/docs/index.html) and [distribute it via an app store even](https://chrome.google.com/webstore).

Answer (score 0):

You could use NW.JS:

https://github.com/nwjs/nw.js

> NW.js is an app runtime based on Chromium and node.js. You can write
>   native apps in HTML and JavaScript with NW.js. It also lets you call
>   Node.js modules directly from the DOM and enables a new way of writing
>   native applications with all Web technologies.

Basically you create a folder with your entire html app. On Windows, just add 4 files (or more depending on your needs): package.json, nw.exe, nw.pak, and icudtl.dat. When you run nw.exe, your app will launch in a packaged version of chrome with node.js support. You can access the file system using node commands directly from your original html.

The drawbacks: NW adds ~60MB to your application and additional memory overhead.